# JMeter Plugins Manager failed to download plugins repository

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am getting following error message when  the plugin manager is launched from JMeter GUI.

[image]

I download the plugins manager jar file, placed it into the `lib/ext` folder and then restarted the JMeter.

My JMeter version is 5.3

Comment: hi @rachel silva , please provide stack trace as text, not screenshot. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a problem with your JDK installation, in particular with [cacerts](https://medium.com/@codebyamir/the-java-developers-guide-to-ssl-certificates-b78142b3a0fc).

I believe re-installing JDK should resolve your issue, [JMeter 5.3](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-5.3/) requires [Java 8](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/) or higher.

If you cannot install or amend software on your machine you can try switching JMeter Plugins Manager to [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) endpoint instead of [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/https), it can be done by adding the next line to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
jpgc.repo.address=http://jmeter-plugins.org/repo/
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are behind a proxy server. Depending on your proxy configuration you need to do additional settings.

If you need to set the proxy server and the port

`JVM_ARGS="-Dhttps.proxyHost=myproxy.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080" jmeter\bin\jmeter.bat`

If you need to set the username and password

`JVM_ARGS="-Dhttps.proxyHost=myproxy.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttp.proxyUser=john -Dhttp.proxyPass=***" jmeter\bin\jmeter.bat`

[Plugin Manager Network Configuration](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManagerNetworkConfiguration/)

**NOTE :**

1. It is recommended to use the [latest version](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) of JMeter
2. You can download the required plugins (jars) and place them into the JMETER_HOME/lib/ext folder and restart the IDE. Plugin Manager does this process when we install the plugins.