# Not able to open Plugin Manager in Apache JMeter 1.6

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have downloaded the Plugin Manager for JMeter from the following link,

https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/

previously it worked fine for me, I never had to do any proxy settings or any changes, but now when I download and try to open it in Jmeter, it gives me the following error:

[image]

JMeter version - 5.4.1

Comment: Please check if this answer help you [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69955399/i-could-not-launch-plugin-manager-in-jmeter-once-jar-file-upload-into-right-path)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're behind a [corporate proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) which uses [MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) certificate to intercept and decrypt secure traffic between your machine and Internet (or other machines in Intranet)

The certificate is not known to Java therefore Plugins Manager cannot securely connect to its repository.

The options are in:

1. Import the certificate as the trusted certificate and point JMeter to use the truststore containing this certificate via `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` system property
2. Configure JMeter Plugins Manager to use [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) protocol for communicating with the [plugins repositor](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/#Plugins-Sources-Configuration)y, it can be done by adding the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   jpgc.repo.address=http://jmeter-plugins.org/repo/
   ```

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
- [Unable to connect to SSL services due to "PKIX Path Building Failed" error](https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/unable-to-connect-to-ssl-services-due-to-pkix-path-building-failed-error-779355358.html)